# For the resistor circuit shown in the picture, what must be the missing resistance to give a total resistance of 252 ohms?

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, series

[image: circuit]

After my calculations, I keep getting 1100 ohms, but the back of the book is saying 85 ohms. 85 seems to fit in better with the other numbers, but I can only get 1100 to add up.

Here's my calculations:

1/(1/(x + 16) + 1/180) + 22 + 75 = 252

x = 1100

Comment: I can *look* at that and see that 85 is *way* too low.

Comment: I have seen more than once books with one or two answers being wrong, so maybe this is the case too.

Answer (score 9):

Your answer is right.  To help gain some intuition ...

Assume that the X is an open circuit, ie. that the series resistance is 22+ 180+ 75 = 277.  that's just a little bit more than the desired result.

Assume that X is a short, then that parallel network is 16//180 = 14.7 (// here means in parallel). the total resistance is 22+14.7+75 = 111.7.

These should tell you that the X value should be large-ish.

Plugging your solution back in:

$$ 22 + \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{1100+16}+\dfrac{1}{180}} + 75 = R_{Total} = 252$$

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to solve these sort of puzzles in a single formula, but rather break it down into small pieces.

1. You know the resulting resistance is 252Ω.
2. Subtract the two known series resistors at both ends from total:

   - $$252 - 22 - 75 = 155Ω$$
3. At this point you known the equivalant resistance of the two parallel branches.
4. Solve the unknown parallel branch R<sub>X</sub> + 16Ω

   - Let's assume  the parallel part is R<sub>T</sub> = 180 // (R<sub>X</sub> + 16Ω) and
   - R<sub>Y</sub> = R<sub>X</sub> + 16Ω, the series equivalent of the top branch.
   - $$\dfrac{1}{R_T} = \dfrac{1}{155Ω} = \dfrac{1}{180Ω}+\dfrac{1}{R_Y}$$
   - $$\dfrac{1}{R_Y} = \dfrac{1}{155Ω} - \dfrac{1}{180Ω} = \dfrac{1}{1116Ω}$$
5. Solve the remaining series resistors:

   - $$R_Y = 1116Ω = R_X + 16$$
   - $$R_X = 1100Ω$$

Advantage of breaking down a problem like this is that your professor can easily follow your reasoning and may give you credit for even when you would have been wrong (which is not the case, your calculations were correct).

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to look at the two resistors 22 Ohm and 75 Ohm. The total contribution of their resistance is their sum, and by linearity, you can either change their order (move one to the other side) or better, combine them into the total reistance of 97 Ohm.

The paralell resistors needs some algebraic manipulation. Any equation of the form 
$${\frac {1}{R_{eq}}} = \frac {1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}$$
where $$R_{eq}$$ is the equivalent resitance of two resitors in paralell, can be rearranged into the form:
$$R_{eq} = \frac {{R_1}{R_2}}{R_1 + R_2}$$
The paralell resistors can be treated as an R_eq in series with the 22 Ohm resistor and the 75 Ohm resistor. Let's add those with R_eq and equate them with the desired resistance of 252 Ohm.
$$ 97\Omega + R_{eq} = 97\Omega + \frac {{R_1}{R_2}}{R_1 + R_2} = 252\Omega$$
Now, let's plug in the numbers. Let R1 = 180 Ohm and R2 = (x + 16) Ohm.
$$ 97\Omega + \frac {{180 \Omega}{(16\Omega + x)}}{180\Omega + 16\Omega + x} = 252\Omega$$
From here on, it's just about solving for one variable using standard algerbra and simplification. (I will allow myself to remove the omega signs for readability here.)
$$ 97\Omega + \frac {{2880 + 180x)}}{196 + x} = 252$$
Let us subtract 97 Ohm from both sides.
$$ \frac {{2880 + 180x)}}{196 + x} = 155$$
Now multiply both sides by (196 + x).
$$ 2880 + 180x = 155(196 + x)$$
Expand.
$$2880 + 180x = 30380 + 155x $$
Separate constants and variables.
$$ 180x - 155x = 27500 $$
And then.
$$ 25x = 27500 $$
And finally:
$$ x = \frac{27500}{25} = 1100$$

Again, do not be intimidated by the rather ugly looking equation for parallell resistors. Using algebra and some practice, these problems can be solved quickly and efficiently, and they will be the basis for more complex circuit analysis. Try to derive the second equation here. Trying to derive equations yourself really helps memorization and most of all, it cements the understanding.